# return from function in another function

Tags: javascript

I have this case:

```js
    function f1(a) {
        a = f2(a);
        // do some other stuff
        console.log("I don't want the function f1 to log this.")
    }
    
    function f2(a) {
        if (a == null) {
            console.log("enters here")
            return;
        }
        return a;
    }
    
    f1(null)
```

if `a` is null, I don't want `f1` to continue with the `console.log()`. What can I change to obtain this behavior? (I know I can do this with some `booleans` but I was wondering if there is another way to solve this)

Comment: You'd have to do it "with some booleans", or else throw an exception to be caught elsewhere.

Comment: In your `f2` function you are already checking if a value is null.  But you're asking how to check if a value is null in your `f1` function?  What exactly isn't working about `if (a == null)`?

Answer (score 0):

You could store the last value of `a` and exit if `temp` is `null`.

```js
function f1(a) {
    let temp = a;
    a = f2(a);
    // do some other stuff
    if (temp === null) return;
    console.log("I don't want the function f1 to log this.");
}

function f2(a) {
    if (a == null) {
        console.log("enters here");
        return;
    }
    return a;
}

f1(null);
```

Answer (score 0):

> if a is null, I don't want f1 to continue with the console.log()

In that case you have to test the value of `a` within the `f1` function:

```js
function f1(a) {
        a = f2(a);
        // do some other stuff
        
        if (a == null) return;
        console.log("I don't want the function f1 to log this.")
    }
    
    function f2(a) {
        if (a == null) {
            console.log("enters here")
            return;
        }
        return a;
    }
    
    f1(null)
```

Answer (score 0):

just return false

```js
    function f1(a) {
        a = f2(a);
        // do some other stuff
        if (!a) return
        console.log("I don't want the function f1 to log this.")
    }
    
    function f2(a) {
        if (a == null) {
            console.log("enters here")
            return false;
        }
        return a;
    }
    
    f1(null)
```